# Is a spouse's vehicle acquired prior to the marriage considered marital property?

Tags: wisconsin

My wife and I were recently married (2 years ago). We are both older (35+) and over the years have acquired our own real estate holdings, investments, etc. We each brought vehicles to the marriage but maintain (license, insure, repair, etc.) them separately. I rarely even know when my wife gets the oil changed. We do occasionally drive the other's vehicles.

Under the laws of marital property, are the vehicles purchased prior to the marriage considered marital property? This is specific to the State of Wisconsin but any US-based opinions are appreciated.

Update - It appears WI is a community property state. It's my understanding that property acquired before the marriage is separate from property acquired after the marriage when everything (minus exceptions like inheritance) is community property and owned equally by both parties. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in WI, the car would be separate property unless it has appreciated in value since it was acquired (rare except in the case of classic cars), or there has been a substantial post-marriage economic investment in the car (which it does not appear that there has been).

This rule would not apply in all states. There is considerable variation on this question between U.S. states.